# Visual Studio's /experimental:module conflicting with Vulkan's core.h causing syntax error - compilation failure

Tags: visual-studio, module, c++17, vulkan, c++20

A little forward message: since I was limited to the number of tags I was able to use, I chose the tag `visual-studio` although this pertains to at least `Visual Studio 2015` minimum which is less of a concern as this is focused more towards the use of `Visual Studio 2017` or `Visual Studio 2019` with the language version being set to either `C++17` or `C++20`.

---

I have noticed a peculiar conflict between these versions of `Visual Studio` and `Vulkan v1.1`

If one is building a `Vulkan` based application and they happen to turn on the compiler flags: `/std:c++latest` and `/experimental:module`

*Documentation found from here:*

- [docs.microsoft/experimental-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/experimental-module?view=vs-2019)
- [docs.microsoft/modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=vs-2019)

and tries to compile and or link against the `Vulkan` library it fails due to a the aforementioned conflict.

---

There is a major failure that is coming from `vulkan_core.h` as some of their defined structures have a member that is named `module` which can be seen from their spec sheet: [khronos/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions...](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo.html)

In `Vulkan's` `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo` structure they have it defined like this:

> ```
> typedef struct VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo {
>     VkStructureType                     sType;
>     const void*                         pNext;
>     VkPipelineShaderStageCreateFlags    flags;
>     VkShaderStageFlagBits               stage;
>     VkShaderModule                      module;
>     const char*                         pName;
>     const VkSpecializationInfo*         pSpecializationInfo;
> } VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo;
> ```

which contains a `VkShaderModule` named `module` and this conflicts with `Visual Studio's` `/experimental:module` compiler flag since this enables `module` to become a `keyword` within the `C++17` and or `C++20` languages.

This feature is available in `Visual Studio 2017` and `Visual Studio 2019`, I'm not 100% sure but I think it is also available in `Visual Studio 2015` as I think this is when Microsoft introduced it.

---

There has been a brief topic, thread or discussion about this found here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556929/enabling-modules-causes-syntax-error-in-vulkan-cor.html They mention that it is being investigated but I don't see much more on this topic than what I've found.

I even tried to search here first to see if there was any mention of it, but my search results were fruitless. So I decided to post this question as more of an awareness and reference to other users as I think that this is an important issue to address since `Vulkan` is becoming a popular 3D Graphics and Compute API tool to use.

---

So to my question(s) regarding this issue:

- Are there any followups other than what was mentioned?
- Is there any work around other than `disabling` the `Visual Studio` compiler feature?
- Where would the responsibility of taking care of this fall to: `The Khronos Group` or `LunarG` who are responsible for the `Vulkan` library, `Microsoft` as they are adding this feature to their `compiler` or would this be something that would concern the actual `C++ Standard`?
- Also; is `module` going to be considered an actual `key word` within the `C++` language from the standard or will this be a Microsoft specific thing?
- Are other compilers such as `gcc` or `Clang` effected by this?

---

I had asked these series of questions to get an overall feedback from the community as a whole.

I would also like to see others contribute to this post adding links of other discussions, plans, and possible resolutions that pertain and or are related to this specific topic making this a reference page for all readers of the C++ community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Are there any followups other than what was mentioned?

The public issue tracker of vulkan has a topic on it: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/568

The resolution is that `module` is to become a contextual keyword so the compiler shouldn't give an error on it.

- Is there any work around other than disabling the Visual Studio compiler feature?

You can edit the vulkan header, the name of the member field doesn't matter for correct operation.

- Where would the responsibility of taking care of this fall to.

Microsoft needs to fix their compiler.

- Also; is module going to be considered an actual key word within the C++ language from the standard or will this be a Microsoft specific thing?

It is going to be a contextual keyword.

- Are other compilers such as gcc or Clang effected by this?

If they implement the contextual keyword correctly then they will not be affected.

Comment: Very nice and informative reply! I hope this helps other readers who are working with or learning how to use Vulkan!